# Unable to read/write contacts to a user mailbox

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In Microsoft 365, we’re able to create a personal contact but we can’t view the contacts of users, let alone add personal contacts to users mailboxes. We keep getting an ErrorAccessDenied message in the output.

Can anyone please advise on how we can get this resolved?

Comment: what is the API call exactly you are using? how are you getting the token?

Comment: The API call I'm making is to GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/contacts

Comment: How are you getting the token? Are you testing it in Graph Explorer or POSTMAN?

Comment: Graph Explorer @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: You cannot test contacts of other users because the authentication is delegated and to test it you need to get token from client credential flow and then call that API. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph Explorer uses user token (delegated permission) to access the contacts data.

It only supports `POST /me/contacts`.

To access others' contacts, we need to implement [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) which uses [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

In this way you can get an application token (application permission). You can use it to access other users' contacts.

You can use Postman to have a test. Microsoft Graph explorer doesn't support client credentials flow.